# Generating serial numbers in Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails app I need a source of unique, sequential (no gaps) integers to use as serial numbers. It must be persistent and allow concurrent access.

Database auto-increment isn't adequate because most don't guarentee the "no gaps" property.

In straight SQL I would just create a one-line table and say (in PostgreSQL) something like:

```
update sequence set value = value + 1 returning value
```

This is apparently standard practice in the SQL world. References exist.

In ActiveRecord I easily created a model the model and found `.increment!` and `.increment_counter` in the documentation. But I can't figure out how to *atomically* retrieve the incremented value.  Locks and transactions don't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use redis (and maybe you already are because of Resque or Sidekiq), you can do an `INCR` on a key, this is atomic and returns the new value.

Comment: Thanks! I thought of this and it will be my fallback solution. Is there a way in redis to ensure persistence on each such transaction? My understanding is that it normally keeps data in RAM and snapshots to disk only periodically.  My concern is that after a redis server crash, repeated numbers could be generated when it comes back up.

Comment: It depends on the configuration. There is an AOF option for persistence that is resilient to system failures. http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: I'll give you the check because yours is a fine solution and accepting my own answer is weird.

Comment: It's not weird to accept one's answer, there are rules for that (e.g. waiting 24h after posting the answer). In any case as you correctly say, it's completely non-portable, so it's as good as mine... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since `update ... returning` acts like a select for output purposes, it turns out you can use `find_by_sql` to both update and get the updated value in one operation.

```
class SequenceNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tag, :value
  validates :tag, :uniqueness => true

  def self.get_next(tag)
    find_by_sql("update sequence_numbers 
                 set value = value + 1 
                 where tag = '#{tag}' 
                 returning value").first.value
  end
end
```

The remaining problem is that this is totally non-portable because `returning` is a pgsql extension.   Maybe the ActiveRecord developers will notice this.